# Use a javascript var from external js script in a Facebook Feed Dialog (js version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I hope this is possible. I have a HTML file that loads an js file using: `<script src="js.js"></script>`
In this script there is a var: `var score = 0;` This var changes when people get points.

Now in this same HTML file I have added the following Dialog script (also see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ for more info):

```
FB.init({appId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxx", status: true, cookie: true});

function postToFeed() {
    // calling the API ...
var obj = {
        method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: '',
    name: 'I just got a new high score of [xx] points!',
    caption: 'Think you can do better?',
    description: 'Join me.'
};

function callback(response) {
    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
}

FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

This script works and the Dialog box appears. Now at the part `[xx] points` I want to show the points people have earned.

I've tried the following:

Pushed the var result to an input field `<input type="text" id="score" name="score" value="0" readonly />` using `$('#score').val(document.getElementById('sc').innerHTML);` in the js.js file, which results that the score shows up in the input field.

And then tried at the `[xx]` part: `' + document.getElementById('score').innerHTML + '`, but this didn't work. Perhaps this approach is wrong and there is a better way, but how can I show the score in the Dialog?

Kind regards,

Maurice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your description `score` is a global variable. you can do something like:

```
var obj = {
    method: 'feed',
    link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
    picture: '',
    name: 'I just got a new high score of ['+ score +'] points!',
    caption: 'Think you can do better?',
    description: 'Join me.'
};
```

Comment: Cool this worked, I didn't know a variable from one script could be used in another. Thanks, learned something today!